# Oracle SQL - last value before "change"

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I am looking for appropriate analytic funcion to solve following issue.
I have following table:

| SCENARIO_KEY | STEP_KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | PREVIOUS_SCENARIO_KEY | PREVIOUS_STEP_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 44 | 20xx04x4 | 0 | 120 | 44 |
| **120** | *44* | **20xx03x3** | 20xx04x4 | 120 | 38 |
| 120 | 38 | 20xx11x0 | 20xx03x3 | 121 | 38 | 121 | 20xx07x2 | 120 |
| 120 | 44 | 20xx07x1 | 20xx07x2 | 120 | 38 |

I need to get first scenario_key (or another identifier) after last change to step with value 44 (step_key = 44).

So the result of this query should be some identifier of the last change - START_DATE of the first row with value 44 after last change (20xx03x3) or SCENARIO_KEY after last change (120).

In short, I need to be able to identify the line of last change to "44" step key.
I need to do it by analytical function (**hint: I probably should use "previous_scenario_key" and "previous_step_key" columns**).

Is there any analytical function to do this?

Thank you